# Query MYSQL to add a product (inner join)

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to find the right query I need. So I have 3 tables, User, products and cart.

- User:     id_user
  username
  password
  usertype
- Products: id_product
  name
  price
- chart:    id_chart
  id_product(FK with Product)
  id_user(FK with User table)

chart is basically a 'middle-table', id_product is a foreign key to id_product in Products table, and id_user is a Foreign Key to id_user in User table.
I can't find a query to insert into chart a product sorting it by name (knowing its id product).

I used this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO chart (id_product, id_user) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?,?) AS pro WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id_product FROM Products WHERE id_product=?)
```

It seems work fine until I don't have id_product = id_user. It's so strange, but when these two ids (which each one refer to different thing, first to the product and second to the user adding to the chart) are equal, MySQL (workbench) is giving me error, like 'duplicate' error but it's not true. Is there something wrong in the query?
What can I do? What else can I check?

I tried different queries but none wanted to work.

Comment: Please give a practical example, using actual values.  This helps to better understand what you're doing.

Comment: Let's say, with the tables i mentioned, the user has id_user=2 and there is a product which has id_product=2, and let's say the chart table is completely empty, if I launch this query:
 INSERT INTO chart (id_product, id_user) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 2,2) AS pro WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id_product FROM Products WHERE id_product=2)
I get this error: Error Code 1060: Duplicate column name 2

Comment: Provide column alias in the select 2,2 part